# View model in ASP.NET MVC / C# without relationship between two tables(model)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model, viewmodel

I have two models without relationship in ASP.NET MVC.

Model 1:

```
public int ExperienceId { get; set; }
public string ExperienceTitle { get; set; }
public string ExperienceText { get; set; }
```

Model 2:

```
public int EducationId { get; set; }
public string EducationTitle { get; set; }
public string EdicationText { get; set; }
```

I want to display the information of these two tables (models) that have no relationship between them using a view model together in one view.

Comment: Do you want to display one instance of each model - or a list of both models? Basically, you need **one** viewmodel class - which then contains whatever you want to display - a single `Model1` and another single `Model2`, or lists/collections thereof

Comment: I want to display both together in one view and only one model can be used in each view, so I have to use one view model to display the information of two tables (models).

Comment: See the answer posted - that's exactly what I'm saying - you need **ONE** `ViewModel` class, which then contains / holds each instance of each class. That's the way to go

Comment: This is the Repository that I want to send as a model to the controller to display in the view, but I don't know what it should return   `public IEnumerable<ShowResumeViewModel> ShowAllResume()
        {
            return ??
        }`

Answer (score 1):

that's easy to do if that i understood from your question, check below code.

```
public class ViewModel{
     public Model1 model_1{ get; set; }
     public Model2 model_2{ get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: How can I use this in Repository?

Comment: This is the Repository that I want to send as a model to the controller to display in the view, but I don't know what it should return   `public IEnumerable<ShowResumeViewModel> ShowAllResume()
        {
            return ??
        }`